# give preference to print array values in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have country table,

i fetch all values and moved into array ,

these value i like to populate into combo/dropdown list ,

here i want to do some magic things,

that is , for my site most of the users coming from uk,us,Australia,Romain and few,

So i like to populate by my preference ,

is there any array will do this magic work, else is it possible mysql query ,

So final question is ,

Populate country name into combo based on my prefernce ,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very annoying to have a country list where not all items can be found at their alphabetical position. I suggest you just duplicate the top 2 or 3 more used items and show them at the top of the complete list:

```
Australia
United Kingdom
United States
---------------
Afghanistan
Albania
Australia
Austria
...
```

I'm not sure, though, why you think this involves any sort of *magic*. You could accomplish this by adding a new `weight` column to the country table in your database that defaults to e.g. `1` and increment it to larger values for items you want to highlight. You can then build your data in PHP or in SQL.

```
SELECT country_id, country_name
FROM country
WHERE weight>1
ORDER BY weight, country_name
UNION ALL
SELECT country_id, country_name
FROM country
ORDER BY country_name
```

Comment: i dont have weght such column..
but i have customer table, in that i have the fieldname like customer_contact no,
this field contain the country-mobile or landline number...

Comment: Not being allowed to alter the database is an important pre-requisite. You should have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

The preference can't be auto-generated I wouldn't have thought since there is no way to know.  What I would do is have a (numeric) preference value in the table along with the country, then when you do the SQL query, order it by the preference field.  You could also increment this field each time a user picks that country so the order of the list changes based on the most common locations of your audience.

Comment: Yes i will do this here after ..
But my past data's dont have such increment fields,
How can i do this...
but i have customer hit table, in that,i have entries of each customer country code,

is it possible do some magic things,that is any join query somthing

Comment: Not 100% on the syntax of it.  But it would be something like "insert into countries(preference) values(select count(*) from hits where hits.country = countries.country)"